# How write the labels of the data inside a Doughnut Chart made with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am making a donut chart with Chart.js and I want to write the label inside each sector of the chart, I have even tried to use the CharPieceLabel plugin but so far I have not been able to render it. I share the code, I really appreciate your help.

Here the HTML code:

```
<div class="grafica col-sm-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <canvas id="chartJSContainerB"></canvas>
</div>

var optionsb = {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data :{
                labels: ["Alfabetización", "Traducción"],
                datasets: [{
                  data: [40,60],
                  backgroundColor:[blue, orange],
                },
                
              
              ],
                
              },
              options:{
              plugins: {
                  labels: {
                    render:'label',
                    fontStyle:'normal',
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontColor: '#fff',
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    arc:true,
                  },
                  legend: {
                    display:false, 
                    
                    },
                  datalabels: {
                    backgroundColor: function(context) {
                      return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                    },
                    color: 'white',
                    font: {
                      weight: 'bold',
                      size:18
                    },
                    padding: 4,
                  }
                }
            }
            }
            // custom render
           
            var ctxb = document.getElementById('chartJSContainerB').getContext('2d');
            new Chart(ctxb, optionsb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost close to achieve it but you need register the `ChartDataLabels` and to show your labels use the `formatter  as function and show your labels as done below:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

var chartInstance = new Chart(document.getElementById("chartJSContainer"), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Alfabetización", "Traducción"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [40, 60],
      backgroundColor: ["blue", "orange"],
    }, ],

  },
  options: {
    plugins: {

      labels: {
        render: 'label',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontColor: '#fff',
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        arc: true,
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,

      },
      datalabels: {
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
        },
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 18
        },
        padding: 4,
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.1/dist/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>

  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

There are [samples](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/advanced/custom-labels.html) available to render different labels or custom labels you can refer to them and make necessary changes.

Comment: Excuse me, I already had Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); in the code, sorry not to have shown it, even so it does not work, it does not show the labels within the sectors of the graph

Comment: But the labels are visible inside the chart in the above example that I have given ? so is not correct ?

Comment: Thank you friend, but I want to show labels, no values

Comment: I want to render labels: ["Alfabetización", "Traducción"], in the sectors of the graph

Comment: Understood. I have made changes in my answer and code snippet, refer to it and let me know if it is correct or not.

Comment: Is there a way to arch the text?

Comment: Not sure if we can display it as arc or not but you can rotate the text as done [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/scriptable/mirror.html)